# How to convert a polar-shaped array into cartesian-shaped array in python?

Tags: python, cartesian-product

I've got a (720, 720) polar matrix (r, theta) that I want to convert into Cartesian (720, 720) matrix (x, y).

I can calculate:

```
x = r*cos(theta)

y = r*sin(theta)
```

I don't know how to resample these results into cartesian shape. How can I resample it into an array?

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data?

Answer (score 0):

assuming your data is either a list of lists [[r, theta],[r, theta]...] or a similarly shaped array, you can use a comprehension:

```
[[r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta)] for r,theta in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got stored your matrix of 720x720 as a simple python list, you'd create a new list like this:

```
from math import sin, cos

lst_polars = [
    (1, 15), (1, 30), (1, 45), (1, 60), (1, 75), (1, 90),
]

cartesian_lst = [
    (r * cos(theta), r * sin(theta)) for r, theta in lst_polars
]

print(cartesian_lst)
```

If you don't want to use comprehension lists, you just do it with a normal for loop:

```
cartesian_lst = []
for r, theta in lst_polars:
    cartesian_lst.append((r * cos(theta), r * sin(theta)))
```

Comment: I don't think it's that simple, because that's definitely the equivalent of an `Mx2` matrix...

Comment: I don't know what you mean, a 2d/3d/Nd matrix can be expressed as a flat list... In my answer I've expressed a 2d MxN matrix as a 1d matrix whose length is (MxN) and the elements are just tuples of (radius, angle)... Of course, you could store the elements as lists, objects, dictionaries, whatever you wish... OP didn't state which type of input data he's using, so i think it's a fair assumption of mine.